# WPBakery Page Builder grid builder how to display time of event

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I'm currently building a WPBakery custom grid to display events (my events are handled with Event Manager), I saw I can add a custom field but I cannot find the correct Field key name.

Does someone knows which key name I am supposed to use?

Already tried event_start_time, _event_start_time, event_time, _event_time...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this key:

```
event_begin
```